# « se passer de » vs « se passer sans »

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

La citation ci-après provient de la page 133 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> se passer de = *to do without*

Ma prèmiere estimation de *to do without* était  **se passer sans** . Sa rareté des résultats sur [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=se+passer+de%2Cse+passer+sans&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cse%20passer%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cse%20passer%20sans%3B%2Cc0) montre qu'il se peut que ma supposition soit fausse. Veuillez faire ressortir les points communs et les divergences ? Je ne savais pas que « de » connote le sens de « sans ».

Encore que je me plie à ce que [**se passer de = se priver**](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_passer_de), je n'appréhende pas pourquoi **se passer sans** est erronée ? Ceci me paraît logique, même à la lumière de Wiktionnaire ?

Comment: Il y a erreur sur la traduction de "*do without*" en français. "*Do without*" en français se dit "faire sans".  il se trouve que le français a aussi la locution verbale "se passer" de pour exprimer la même idée. On peur "faire sans" et faire "avec" en français.

Answer (score 6):

La distinction est entre « se passer » (*happen/take place*) et la locution  verbale « se passer de » qui peut s'employer à la place de « faire sans » (*do without*).

**Se passer** signifie « avoir lieu », « se dérouler » :

> Il s'est passé quelque chose d'étrange.
>
> La cérémonie s'est passée sans encombres.

**Se  passer de** signifie « se priver », « s'abstenir » :

> Il n'y a plus de café, je devrai m'en passer. / Je me passerai de café.
>
> Mon ordinateur vient de me lâcher, je me serais bien passé de cette
> tuile en ce moment.
>
> Ceci se passe de commentaires.

« De » seul ne peut pas signifier « sans ».

Si tu as trouvé « se passer » (*happen, take place*) suivi de « sans » sur google c'est tout simplement parce que dans la phrase  le complément indirect de « se passer » était introduit par la préposition « sans » :

> La discussion s'est passée sans heurts / sans encombres.

mais bien sûr ce pourrait être une autre préposition :

> L'entretien s'est passé avec le patron.
>
> L'entretien s'est passé dans le bureau du patron.

Comment: @LePressentiment: **Je l'ai déjà expliqué dans la réponse ci-dessus.** La locution verbale c'est « Se passer **de** ». Quand « sans » se trouve après se passer c'est qu'il introduit le complément indirect qui suit. La rencontre /s'est passée/ /sans lui./ Et dans ce cas « se passer » veut dire « se dérouler ».

Comment: Merci. Prière de me pardonner si je l'oublie, mais pourquoi est-ce que ma 1e conjecture, **se passer sans**, est fausse ? J'imaginais que "without" se traduit par **sans** ? Veuillez répondre dans votre réponse.

Comment: @LePressentiment: c'est déjà dit : **se passer veut dire "se priver"**, se priver sans quelque chose est un non sens, c'est absurde, ça n'a aucune logique !

Comment: Merci. Dans votre commentaire ci-dessus, avez-vous voulu dire que se passer DE = "se priver" ? Votre réponse renferme le DE. Encore que j'accepte que **se passer de = se priver**, je n'appréhende pas pourquoi **se passer sans** est erronée ? Ceci me paraît logique ?

Comment: @LePressentiment. Si tu veux  absolument utiliser "sans" alors il faut t'en tenir à "faire sans".

Comment: Merci. Hélas, je n'appréhende pas encore pourquoi **se passer sans** est erronée ? Ceci me paraît logique ?

Comment: @LePressentiment. parce que si tu ne mets pas  "de" après  "se passer" se passer a un autre sens. C'est l'objet de toute ma réponse. Il n'y a rien d'autre à comprendre "se passer" et la locution verbale "se passer de" ont des sens différents. Si tu veux un synonyme de "faire sans" il faut employer obligatoirement "se passer de" "se passer de sans" avec deux prépositions est impossible, absurde.

Comment: @LePressentiment Le problème, c'est que tu insistes pour avoir une réponse à une question qui n'en a pas! "se passer de" est, à toute fins pratiques, une expression entière indécomposable, et ça revient à insister pour savoir pourquoi on met un *to* après *need* mais pas après *must*. En syntaxe comme pour le genre des noms, il y a des choses qu'ils faut apprendre par cœur sans avoir une règle pratique. Si apprendre une langue étrangère se réduisait à des règles, les ordinateurs pourraient le faire.