# Traduction de "passer mes examens"

Tags: traduction, anglais

passer = to pass (a location)

then why does:

passer mes examens = to sit/take/do my tests

see https://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/passer+mes+examens.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context *passer* and *pass* are false cognates (faux amis).
The pair is a very basic one as user @Lambie remarks.

> passer ses examens = to sit/take/do his/her exams

Cf.

> Réussir ses examens = to pass his/her exams.

See, e.g.

https://www.fluentu.com/blog/french/faux-amis-french-false-friends-cognates/

https://www.9h05.com/10-exemples-frequents-de-faux-amis-anglais-francais/

Google 'passer un examen false cognates'.

See also the question

[How to say "I am taking an exam" in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/how-to-say-i-am-taking-an-exam-in-french)

PS

Se passer de etc. is not relevant here (thanks @Lambie)

Comment: Yes, and this is a very basic false friend.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the verification:-)!

Comment: @user716881 I suggest that you post a new question for 'se passer'.

Comment: @Dimitris I found a question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8720/se-passer-de-vs-se-passer-sans

Comment: @user716881 Bravo. If you have queries don't hesitate to ask a question about se passer. Even if there is an old post, both the question and the answer are in French.

Comment: @user716881 se passer de etc. is not relevant here.

Comment: @Lambie I know - I was just wondering. Thanks.